# Consolidate overlapping and consecutive date range in SQL

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, date-range

[image]

The above shows my table in SQL database.

I want to consolidate the startdate-enddate such that both consecutive and overlapping date ranges are handled.

My desired output is

[image]

I am looking for solution **without using master..spt_values**

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Azure Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.  This was done using SQL Server so you should be safe

```
create table #main
(
id int not null identity(1,1),
ref int null,
ref2 int null,
year int null,
startdate datetime null,
enddate datetime null
)

insert into #main (ref, ref2, year,startdate,enddate) values( 34321,111,2021, '20210201','20210501')
insert into #main (ref, ref2, year,startdate,enddate) values( 12345,111,2021, '20210101','20210228')
insert into #main (ref, ref2, year,startdate,enddate) values( 21111,111,2021, '20210301','20210531')
insert into #main (ref, ref2, year,startdate,enddate) values( 21111,111,2021, '20210601','20210801')
insert into #main (ref, ref2, year,startdate,enddate) values( 21111,111,2021, '20210401','20211001')
insert into #main (ref, ref2, year,startdate,enddate) values( 12345,111,2021, '20210301','20210331')
insert into #main (ref, ref2, year,startdate,enddate) values( 34222,123,2021, '20210801','20210930')
insert into #main (ref, ref2, year,startdate,enddate) values( 34222,123,2021, '20211101','20211130')

select * from #main

select ref, max(ref2) as ref2, YEAR, MIN(startdate) as startdate, 
MAX(enddate) as enddate
from #main
group by ref, YEAR
```

Comment: 34222    123 2021-08-01 00:00:00.000 2021-11-30 00:00:00.000
The result of 34222 shld be two rows but I get the above result.... 2021-08-01 2021-09-30 and 2021-11-01 2021-11-30

Comment: Hi PRI.  The query does answer your question and I can't see how you'd get the 34222 row to appear twice as required.  I'll take another quick look and see what I can do

Comment: The row 34222 has two rows in the input . first, startdate-Aug and enddate-Sept . second, startdate-Nov and enddate-Nov....Since October is not there in the range...My desired output is two rows...please refere the question. But this query returns one row will include october too....

Comment: Sorry but I can't see how that can be done given how my query works.  How come the other rows e.g. 21111 is fine to show one row with the consecutive days but not 34222?...sorry just saw your earlier comment...my bad...I'll have another think

Comment: 21111 -> if u see all the start date and end date....the daterange overlaps....so all months are covered from march till october...so its fine...but if there is a gap, then there shld be multiple rows

Comment: I get what you're saying...didn't catch the question correctly first time...

Answer (score 0):

Found this option to achieve my desired output...but in two steps.
First consolidate the overlapping date ranges and then consolidate consecutive date ranges.
But wanna know whether there is more efficient way to do this.

```
DECLARE @TempTableFinal TABLE
        (   
            Id  INT,
            EmployeeId              VARCHAR(50),
            CompanyId INT,
            StartDate   DATETIME,
            EndDate DATETIME    
        );
DECLARE @TempTableFinal2 TABLE
(   
    EmployeeId              VARCHAR(50),
    CompanyId       INT,
    StartDate   DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME    
);

INSERT INTO @TempTableFinal2

SELECT
s1.EmployeeId,s1.CompanyId,
s1.StartDate,
MIN(t1.EndDate) AS EndDate
FROM test2 s1
INNER JOIN test2 t1 ON s1.EmployeeId = t1.EmployeeId and s1.CompanyId = t1.CompanyId and s1.StartDate <= t1.EndDate
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test2 t2
WHERE t1.EmployeeId = t2.EmployeeId and t1.CompanyId = t2.CompanyId and t1.EndDate >= t2.StartDate AND t1.EndDate < t2.EndDate)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test2 s2
WHERE s1.EmployeeId = s2.EmployeeId and s1.CompanyId = s2.CompanyId and s1.StartDate > s2.StartDate AND s1.StartDate <= s2.EndDate)
GROUP BY s1.EmployeeId,s1.StartDate,s1.CompanyId
ORDER BY s1.StartDate


 ;with cte as (
    select EmployeeId,CompanyId,StartDate, EndDate
    from @TempTableFinal2
    union all
    select t.EmployeeId,t.CompanyId,cte.StartDate, t.EndDate
    from cte
    join @TempTableFinal2 t on cte.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId and cte.CompanyId = t.CompanyId and DateAdd(d,1,cte.EndDate) = t.EnrollmentStart
), cte2 as (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId, EndDate order by StartDate)
    from cte
)

INSERT INTO @TempTableFinal
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeId, StartDate) as Id,EmployeeId,CompanyId,StartDate, max(EndDate) enddate
from cte2
where rn=1
group by EmployeeId, StartDate,CompanyId
order by EmployeeId, StartDate;

select * from @TempTableFinal
```